# iOS instance variable gets "NULLED" for unknown reason

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an instance variable that looks like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Post *post;
```

I set it in a custom init method like this:

```
- (id)initWithPageType:(int)pageType andPost:(Post *)post
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"StreamViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.post = post;
        self.pageType  = pageType;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It is never NULL in this case. I also have a `NSFetchedResultsController` with the following delegate method:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    [...]
    // Here self.post == nil for some reason...
    [...]
```

Anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I think the ownership of the post object is expired somehow, that is making it to nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own setter, then put a breakpoint on a statement in the setter. Now you will know what code is setting it.